# I have a javascript that checks if my form is valid and it stops checking after a certain field

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, alert

So I made a form in a table in html and the javascript code checks till the (creditcard.value.length) after that the code doesn't check anything

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function ispsd(form) {
       var passed = false;

       if (form.Fullname.value.length < 4) {
         alert("Enter a valid Full Name");
       } else if (form.Email.value.indexOf("@") == -1) {
         alert("Enter a valid E-mail adress.")
       } else if (form.Email.value.indexOf(".") == -1) {
         alert("Enter a valid E-mail adress.")
       } else if (form.Cardholder.value.length < 3) {
        alert("Card Holder name is not Valid.")
       } else if (form.Creditcard.value.length != 16) {
         alert("Credit card number is not valid.")
       } else if (isNan(form.Creditcard.value)) {
         alert("Credit card number cannot contain letters.")
       } else if (isNan(form.Zip.value)) {
         alert("Enter a valid Postal Code.")
       } else if ((form.Expyear.value) * 1 < 2021) {
         alert("Credit Card has Expired.")
       } else if (isNan(form.Expyear.value)) {
         alert("Enter a valid Year.")
       } else if (form.cvv.value.length != 3) {
         alert("Enter a valid CVV.")
       } else if (isNan(form.cvv.value)) {
         alert("CVV cannot contain letters.")
       } else {
         passed = true;
       }
       return passed;
     }
</script>
```

and the thing is when I moved the (form.Expyear.value) * 1 < 2021) above the (form.Creditcard.value.length != 16) the validation worked and when I tried to add all the (else if) above the Credit card check it didn't work

don't know what's the problem
if anyone can help I would be thankful

Comment: what do you mean from validation works?

Comment: like for example when I insert a credit card number that the length of it is less than 16 an error pops up saying "Credit card number is not valid." the validation works but the rest does not even if I inesrted something wrong for example in the cvv check I wanted the user to insert only 3 digits but if you insert 2 the form still works

Comment: you have a reference error, `isNan` is not defined, it should be `isNaN`

Answer (score 1):

You can always use console.log() to check what the variable has

```
function validate(form) {
    if (form.Fullname.value.length < 4) {
        alert('Enter a valid Full Name');
        document.form.Fullname.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (form.Email.value.indexOf('@') == -1 || form.Email.value.indexOf('.') == -1) {
        alert('Enter a valid E-mail adress.');
        document.form.Email.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (form.Cardholder.value.length < 3) {
        alert('Card Holder name is not Valid.');
        document.form.Cardholder.focus();
        return false;
    }

    console.log(form.Creditcard.value);

    if (isNaN(form.Creditcard.value)) {
        alert('Credit card number cannot contain letters.');
        document.form.Creditcard.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (form.Creditcard.value.length < 16) {
        alert('Credit card number is not valid.');
        document.form.Creditcard.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (isNaN(form.Zip.value)) {
        alert('Enter a valid Full Name');
        document.form.Zip.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (isNaN(form.Expyear.value)) {
        alert('Enter a valid Year.');
        document.form.Expyear.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (Number(form.Expyear.value) < 2021) {
        alert('Enter a valid Year.');
        document.form.Expyear.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (isNaN(form.cvv.value)) {
        alert('CVV cannot contain letters.');
        document.form.cvv.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (form.cvv.value.length != 3) {
        alert('Enter a valid Year.');
        document.form.cvv.focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Try to remove the * 1, not sure what's the purpose there
- isNaN, and not isNan

I would also handle it differently, what you need is to return true if they pass, rather than identify errors, for example, the demo here below. For example, it will pass your test if you have more than 16 numbers since you're checking `x !== 16`

```js
function validate() {
  var x, text;

    // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
    x = document.getElementById("cc").value;

    // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
    if (!isNaN(x) && x.length > 3 && x.length <= 16) {
      text = "Input OK";
    } else {
      text = "Input not valid";
    }
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>Please write only numbers, from 4 to 16 maximum characters</p>
<input type="number" id="cc"/><br>
<span id="error"></span><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="validate()" />
```

Last but not least, this is so verbose and difficult to maintain, I strongly suggest using a library like this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator to handle validation, or even jQuery has .validate() useful function for beginner.

Comment: Thank you good sir, I will try it out. 
as for the *1 the lecturer told me to do so, this is my first semester learning so I'm still new to this and some of the stuff I wrote is what we learned to do so far.
Again thanks for your time bro I appreciate it.

Comment: let me know if you have any question :)